# Can I upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 with ubuntu 13.10 already installed?

Tags: upgrade, windows

The title is self-explanatory. I have Windows and ubuntu installed on separate partitions. Currently using the Grub bootloader to switch between OS. If there's any other information I need to provide let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, but keep in mind, that there is quite chance that Windows will overwrite Master Boot Record during upgrade process and hence disable GRUB, so you will have to reinstall GRUB after that. Beside that, you Ubuntu installation will remain intact.

I you need instruction how to fix bootloader, look into the last section of my [GRUB2 Cookbook](https://github.com/mikobartnicki/howto/blob/master/grub2_cookbook.txt) quick memo.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply! It has been a while since I have installed ubuntu, so could you please explain the process of reinstalling GRUB?

Comment: I added link to quick memo about fixing bootloader.